# How to push floated left and right divs right next to a middle one

Tags: jquery, html, css, zurb-foundation

Image:

[image]

I would like to have them all centered in the middle of the page, with the right and left floated divs sticking right next to the one in the middle.

I can achieve this effect for a particular screen size by using `margin-left: [val]px` and `margin-right: [val]px` for the left and right floated divs. However, since the width of the page is dynamic(I am using  ZURB Foundation 5), I can't specify concrete values, as different displays would render the page in a different way, often resulting in the middle div being pushed down.

This is the code I have now:

HTML

```
<div id="container">

<div class="hide-for-small" id="templatemo_wrapper_left">
    <table>
        .
        .
        .
    </table>
</div>

<div class="hide-for-small " id="templatemo_wrapper_right">
    <table>
        .
        .
        .
    </table>
</div>

<div class="center">
    .
    .
    .
</div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
    #templatemo_wrapper_left {
    float: left;
    width: 120px;
}

    #templatemo_wrapper_right {
    float: right;
    width: 120px;
}

    #container {
    text-align: center;
}

.center {
    text-align: left;
    display: inline-block;
}

    #templatemo_wrapper_left table, #templatemo_wrapper_right table {
    position: relative;
    border: none;
    text-align: center;
    width: 120px;
}
```

I've been trying to fix this issue for a while, so would appreciate some help. Thanks!

Comment: Can we see some code please?

Comment: wrap all elements with div and set { max-width: ...; margin: auto } to it.

Comment: Any reason why you aren't using the grid system in foundation?

Comment: I am using it. However, the standard layout of the grid leaves too much space on the sides and I am confused about customising with Sass. Therefore, I have a full width layout and I am using the grid within the .center DIV.

Comment: @Barzev You want something like this https://jsfiddle.net/51xLqm7f/

Comment: @SrinivasPai, thank you, but this didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you really need the floating? Or could [`display:flex`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) be an option? Then it becomes quite simple:

```css
/* solution */
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
/* for demo purposes */
* { height: 50px }
.container { width: 400px; background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.1) }
.content { width: 100px; background-color: green }
.hidden-xs { width: 10px; background-color: blue }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="hidden-xs"></div>
  <div class="content"></div>
  <div class="hidden-xs"></div>
</div>
```